Getting TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "display" in "{" when passing event data to fullcalendar from eventSources link
Using the following snippet in my javascript:
eventSources: {
            url: '../assets/php/getevents.php',
            method: 'POST',
            extraParams: {
                cuids: cuids,
                uid: uid
            }
        }

I passed this JSON into fullcalendar:
{"id":"3_2","allDay":false,"start":"2024-05-11 11:00","end":"2024-05-11 14:00","title":"Adventist Church","editable":true,"backgroundColor":"#00BFFF","textColor":"#000000"}

Oh, I was in week view (12 - 18 May) and had used the back arrow on the calendar to get to the previous week. There were no events recorded in the database for 12 - 18 May. No error or data was held or reported for week 12 - 18 May. The above JSON contains the data from the transition back (week 5 - 11 May)
I received this error in my console:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "display" in "{"

There many lines following, these are the latest to give clue where it failed.
refineProps internal-common.js:1622
    refineEventDef internal-common.js:3206
    parseEvent internal-common.js:3182
    parseEvents internal-common.js:3310
    receiveRawEvents internal-common.js:3567
    reduceEventStore internal-common.js:3532
    _handleAction index.js:1317
    runTask index.js:1136
    drain index.js:1128
    drained internal-common.js:156
    tryDrain internal-common.js:138
    request internal-common.js:101
    request index.js:1114
    node_modules Calendars.js:54164
    node_modules Calendars.js:53548
    node_modules Calendars.js:53861
    promise callback*fetch index.js:906
    fetchSource index.js:581
    fetchSourcesByIds index.js:569
    fetchDirtySources index.js:552
    reduceEventSources index.js:510
    _handleAction index.js:1316
    runTask index.js:1136

I then ran console log in internal-common.js in the fullcalendar node module as below:
function refineProps(input, refiners) {
    let refined = {};
    let extra = {};
    for (let propName in refiners) {
        console.log(input);
        console.log(refiners);
        console.log(propName);
        
        if (propName in input) {
            refined[propName] = refiners[propName](input[propName]);
        }
    }
    for (let propName in input) {
        if (!(propName in refiners)) {
            extra[propName] = input[propName];
        }
    }
    return { refined, extra };
}

I note that there is not an object shown after endRecur, unlike all the other objects, only the character {, which does not make sense to me:
The last lines of that log are:
duration internal-common.js:1620
Object { editable: false }
internal-common.js:1618
Object { display: String(), editable: Boolean(), startEditable: Boolean(), durationEditable: Boolean(), constraint: identity(raw), overlap: identity(raw), allow: identity(raw), className: parseClassNames(raw), classNames: parseClassNames(raw)
, color: String(), … }
internal-common.js:1619
daysOfWeek internal-common.js:1620
Object { editable: false }
internal-common.js:1618
Object { display: String(), editable: Boolean(), startEditable: Boolean(), durationEditable: Boolean(), constraint: identity(raw), overlap: identity(raw), allow: identity(raw), className: parseClassNames(raw), classNames: parseClassNames(raw)
, color: String(), … }
internal-common.js:1619
startTime internal-common.js:1620
Object { editable: false }
internal-common.js:1618
Object { display: String(), editable: Boolean(), startEditable: Boolean(), durationEditable: Boolean(), constraint: identity(raw), overlap: identity(raw), allow: identity(raw), className: parseClassNames(raw), classNames: parseClassNames(raw)
, color: String(), … }
internal-common.js:1619
endTime internal-common.js:1620
Object { editable: false }
internal-common.js:1618
Object { display: String(), editable: Boolean(), startEditable: Boolean(), durationEditable: Boolean(), constraint: identity(raw), overlap: identity(raw), allow: identity(raw), className: parseClassNames(raw), classNames: parseClassNames(raw)
, color: String(), … }
internal-common.js:1619
startRecur internal-common.js:1620
Object { editable: false }
internal-common.js:1618
Object { display: String(), editable: Boolean(), startEditable: Boolean(), durationEditable: Boolean(), constraint: identity(raw), overlap: identity(raw), allow: identity(raw), className: parseClassNames(raw), classNames: parseClassNames(raw)
, color: String(), … }
internal-common.js:1619
endRecur internal-common.js:1620
{ internal-common.js:1618
Object { display: String(), editable: Boolean(), startEditable: Boolean(), durationEditable: Boolean(), constraint: identity(raw), overlap: identity(raw), allow: identity(raw), className: parseClassNames(raw), classNames: parseClassNames(raw)
, color: String(), … }
internal-common.js:1619
display internal-common.js:1620

Please advise.

If you think you've found an internal bug in fullCalendar, there's probably not much we can do about it here. See https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs for the procedure for reporting these. Make sure you're running this on the very latest release of fullCalendar though, in case any bugs have been fixed in the meantime.
